# intalar libncourses.so.5 not found

Tags: ubuntu, instalacion

Buenas quiero instalar libncourses.so.5 para poder instalar la ISE de Xilinx 14.7.
El problema es que he seguido varias guías de internet para instalar libncourses, y en todas me da fallo a la hora de instalar, me dice lo siguiente:

```
Err:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libtinfo5 amd64 6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

Err:2 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libncurses5 amd64 6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1

  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/ncurses/libncurses5_6.1+20190803-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
```

No sé como solucionar este error, el comando para instalar que uso, y que provoca el error de arriba es:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

Answer (score 1):

El error "404 Not Found" quiere decir que el archivo no se encuentra porque muy probablemente ya hay una versión mas reciente de dicho paquete.

Hay que actualizar la lista de paquetes disponibles primero y después intentar instalarlo nuevamente.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```